# Perl's HTML::Form::ForceValue equivalent in Python

Tags: python, html, automation, mechanize

I m trying to automate logging into a website using Python's `mechanize` module.Following is the login `form` code:

```
    <TD><B>Site:</B></TD>
    <TD><SELECT name="site" class="drpdwn" size=1 width="200" onChange="populateZones(this, '');"><OPTION value="">Select a site</OPTION></SELECT>
    <INPUT type="hidden" name="shortsite" size="3" value=""></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD><B>Zone:</B></TD>
    <TD><SELECT name="zone" class="drpdwn" size=1 width="100"><OPTION value="">Select a zone</OPTION></SELECT></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD><B>User ID:</B></TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" name="user" size=20 value=""></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD><B>Password:</B></TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="password" name="password" size=20></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD><INPUT name="submit1" type="submit" value="Log On" style="color: #003399; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="reset1" type="reset" value="Reset" style="color: #003399; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt" onClick="resetform();">
    </TD>
```

I m able to parse and populate `user`, `password` and `shortsite` fields without any difficulty. The problem comes in while populating the `zone` drop down list. As is evident from the HTML code above that the webpage is using `populateZones` javascript function to populate the zones. I m looking for a way to force the zone value as stored in the configuration file. I have done similar things in the past using  `HTML::Form::ForceValue`.Is there any equivalent in python?

Below is an excerpt from the python script that i m working on to automate the login:


`br['user']     = self.config['COMMON.USER']

br['password'] = self.config['COMMON.PASSWORD']`

`if 'COMMON.SITE' in self.config and 'COMMON.ZONE' in self.config:`
    `try:`
        `br.form.set_all_readonly(False)`
        `br.form["shortsite"] = self.config['COMMON.SITE']`
        `br.form.find_control(name="zone").set_value_by_label([self.config['COMMON.ZONE']])`
    `except ControlNotFoundError, err:`
        `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`
        `logger.info(str(err))`

Comment: No comments!! Does that mean that there is no way this can be done in python? or is it because lack of details... Please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this going by emmulating the javascript. Sharing the code as might be of some help:

```
br.select_form(predicate=self.__form_with_fields("user", "password"))  
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)  
br['user']           = self.config['COMMON.USER']  
br['password']       = self.config['COMMON.PASSWORD']  
br.form["shortsite"] = self.config['COMMON.SITE'] 

zone1 = br.form.find_control("zone")

#Add drop down list value dynamically like the Javascript does
mechanize.Item(zone1, {"contents": "Hurray","value": "Hurray"})

#Choose the just added option
br.form["zone"] = ["Hurray"]
```